# useradd denies home directory creation Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: bash, git, sh

I'm trying to set up a git user, but am getting the error

`useradd: cannot create directory /srv/data/git` when running this command

```
sudo useradd                      \
  --create-home                   \
  --skel      /dev/null           \
  --home-dir  /srv/data/git       \
  --shell     /usr/bin/git-shell  \
  --comment   'Web Archive VCS'   \
git
```

Why am I having trouble? When creating the directory first, (`mkdir -p /srv/data/git`) I receive the following two errors/warnings.

```
useradd: warning: the home directory already exists.
Not copying any file from skel directory into it.
```

This should be very straight forward, but is having issues for unknown reasons to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `useradd` uses `mkdir` or something akin to if **WITHOUT** the `-p` flag,
this means that the directory **MUST** exist up to the last portion of the path. This seems like a functionality gap.

In order to fix the above, I/you will need to `mkdir -p /srv/data` before running the switch for `... --create-dir --home-dir /src/data/git ...`